# Angular ngx-bootstrap is incorrectly writing to 2 different input boxes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using this ngx-bootstrap datepicker for angular 5 -  unless anyone can suggest a "better" one.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

> I'm having trouble with 2 input text boxes with an event click of a checkbox is is affecting Both inputs!

HTML template

input box #1

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="HearingDate" name="HearingDate" id="HearingDate"
       [minDate]="minDate" 
       [maxDate]="maxDate" 
       #dp="bsDatepicker" 
       bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue"
       [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
```

input box #2

```
<input type="text" 
     class="form-control" 
     [(ngModel)]="ReporterDate" name="ReporterDate" id="ReporterDate"
     [minDate]="minDate" 
     [maxDate]="maxDate" 
     #xdp="bsDatepicker" 
     bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue"
     [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
```

ngModel binding

```
ReporterDate: any;
HearingDate: any;
```

**Checkbox event function**

```
onReporterChange(){
   //this.reporter = !this.reporter;

    var currentDt = new Date();
    var mm = currentDt.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = currentDt.getDate();
    var yyyy = currentDt.getFullYear();
    var date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    //BELOW IS SETTING NOT ONLY ReporterDate, but HearingDate too!
    this.ReporterDate = date;

}
```

So the problem is this

> function is SETTING NOT ONLY ReporterDate, but HearingDate too!

**Perhaps it is all in the #dp or something that I don't quite understand  ( template reference variables)   ??**

Comment: where is `onReporterChange()` in your template? I mean how `onReporterChange` function called?

Comment: it is on a (click)  on a checkbox